# How to get a callback function in vb6 with TaskDialogIndirect?

Tags: vb6, taskdialog

I'm using TaskDialogIndirect in VB6. It's working great, and I even have links working (with enabling TDF_ENABLE_HYPERLINKS) in the pszFooter member of TASKDIALOGCONFIG.

The problem is that while the cursor turns into a "hand" when hovering over the link, I don't know how to get the TaskDialogIndirect's TASKDIALOGCONFIG.pfCallback member to point to a custom function of mine, so I *can* actually direct the user to the hyperlink shown.

```
tdi.pszFooter = StrPtr("<a href=" & Chr$(34) & "www.cnn.com" & Chr$(34) & ">www.cnn.com</a>")
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function FnPtrToLong(ByVal lngFnPtr As Long) As Long
    FnPtrToLong = lngFnPtr
End Function
```

Comment: You'd also need to do

Ptr = fnPtrToLong(Addressof MyFunction)